# How to get rid of ServerNT ProductType after switching Windows 10/11 back from ServerRdsh SKU?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

There is a special SKU of Windows 10/11, ServerRdsh, which allows multiple RDP connections to a single Windows instance. However, ServerRdsh reports itself as "ServerNT" in ProductType, causing some softwares' malfunction. Switching from ServerRdsh to other Windows SKUs keeps `ServerNT` ProductType. How should I get it back to the original `WinNT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who misunderstood the question: There is an edition of windows called **ServerRdsh** just like Home, Pro, or Enterprise. This edition gives you the classic **windows 10/11 desktop experience** with the extra functionality of **multiple rdp connections** at the same time. *(Normal client operating systems can have only 1 active session)*. This is somewhat like the Windows Server RDSH role, but completely different windows image is needed.

I also recommend using the command line tool (slmgr) to remove the license and install a new one, because this information is likely stored at multiple locations.

But the registry key you are looking for is here:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions
ProductType REG_SZ ServerNT
```

You can change it back to `WinNT` but as I said, multiple keys differ among the two editions. And we don't exactly know what will happen if you just change a few of them. For example this key is also different on the two systems, but contains random numbers:

```
OSProductPfn REG_SZ Microsoft.Windows.##############
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Windows Server with the RDSH role.

There is no upgrade path from Windows Server to Windows 10.
You will need to clean-install Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the ServerNT ProductType, you need explicitly remove the ServerRdsh license instead of changing product key in settings.

```
slmgr /upk
slmgr /ipk <The Windows Key to be installed>
```

After a reboot, everything should be normal now. Though I highly recommend doing an [in-place upgrade, aka repair installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/repair-or-in-place-upgrade) using ISO to get rid of quirks left in registry, like built-in Administrator account seen on login screen.